# QPainter::begin: Widget painting can only begin as a result of a paintEvent

Tags: c++, qt, qpainter

The code works but I get the following warning message while I press the mouse while it is executing:  ??

```
QPainter::begin: Widget painting can only begin as a result of a paintEvent
QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
QPainter::drawRects: Painter not active
```

added modification further down

---

```
#include <QTextEdit>

class QTextEditEnter : public QTextEdit
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    QTextEditEnter(QWidget *_parent);

protected:
    virtual void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *_event);
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *evt);
    int m_color;
    void mouseDoubleClickEvent(QMouseEvent *e);
signals:
    void signalPressEnter();
};
```

---

```
#include "qtexteditenter.h"
#include <qpainter.h>
#include <QMouseEvent>

QTextEditEnter::QTextEditEnter(QWidget *_parent) :
    QTextEdit(_parent)
{
    this->setFrameStyle(QFrame::Sunken);
    m_color = 0;
    setAttribute(Qt::WA_PaintOutsidePaintEvent, true);
}


void QTextEditEnter::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *_event)
{
    QPainter pnt( viewport() );
    pnt.setPen( QColor( 255, 0, 0, 0xff ));
    pnt.drawRect( 0, 0, width()-1, height()-1);
}


void QTextEditEnter::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *e)
{
    QPainter p(this->viewport());
    p.setPen(QColor(0,0,0,0xff));
    p.drawRect(this->viewport()->rect());
    p.begin(this);

    switch(m_color){
        case 0:
            p.setPen(Qt::red);
            break;
        case 1:
            p.setPen(Qt::green);
            break;
    }
    p.drawEllipse(e->pos(),2,2);
    p.end();
}

void QTextEditEnter::mouseDoubleClickEvent(QMouseEvent *e)
{
    m_color++;
    if (m_color > 1) m_color = 0;

}
```

------------------- Modified ----------------

```
void QTextEditEnter::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *_event)
{

    if(1){
        QPainter pnt( this->viewport());

        pnt.setPen( QColor( 0xff, 0, 0, 0xff ));
        pnt.drawRect( 0, 0, width()-1, height()-1);

        pnt.setPen( QColor( 0, 0xff, 0, 0xff ));
        pnt.drawRect( 10, 10, width()-20, height()-20);
    }

    if(flagModify == 1){
        QPainter p(this->viewport());

        switch(m_color){
            case 0:
                p.setPen(Qt::red);
                break;
            case 1:
                p.setPen(Qt::green);
                break;
        }

        p.begin(this);
        p.drawEllipse(x, y, 2, 2);
        p.end();

        flagModify = 0;
    }
}


void QTextEditEnter::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *e)
{
    x = e->pos().x();
    y = e->pos().y();

    flagModify = 1;
    this->update(this->rect());
}
```

Comment: The error explains the problem clearly - you're trying to draw in the mousePressEvent with p.begin, rather than rendering in the paintEvent function. While it may appear to work, it may cause problems later; certainly for performance if nothing else. If you want to cause objects to paint when the mouse is pressed, use the update function of the window to let the object know that it needs to repaint itself.

Comment: added modification but same error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You get the message because painting to the widget's paint device is only allowed inside the paint event. If you use it outside the paint event, there's no guarantee it will work. So, instead of painting inside the `mousePressEvent`, set a state variable (e.g. `isPressed`) and call `update`, passing the widget's rect. This will trigger the paint event, where you can check the state variable and paint the widget accordingly.

Comment: You are calling `paintEvent()` directly, which is the same as running the code outside the paint event. You must call `update(this->rect())` and let Qt call `paintEvent`. Also, you're building the QPainter using another widget's (viewport) paint device. That may also cause the problem.

Comment: made another modification here... this time the ellipses arenet draw.  And I get the warning: QPainter::begin: Painter already active.

Comment: Qt is really trying to help you with the warnings. Read the [QPainter::begin](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgui/qpainter.html#begin) docs. I'm sure you can figure this one out.

Comment: [This one](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtgui/qpainter.html#QPainter-2) is also really good.

Answer (score 0):

In your example do **not** call p.begin(this); inside

```
void QTextEditEnter::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *_event) {...}
```

if you want to get rid of the warning message.